# Please Explain How to Solve this Equation in Reals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

When I solve the equation $(x-1) \cdot \sqrt{x^2 - 4}=0$ in the set of all real numbers (***I have not known about complex numbers***). I do following steps.

***First step.*** I solve the inequality $x^2 - 4x \geqslant 0$, I have $x \leqslant -2 \lor x \leqslant$ 2.$

***Second step.*** I solve the given equation by solving
$x - 1 = 0$ and $x^2 - 4 = 0$. I get $x = -2 \lor x = 1 \lor x = 2.$

***Third step.*** Check the above roots, we have the roots of the given equation are $x = -2$ or $x = 2.$

Thus, the given equation have two roots $x = -2$ or $x = 2.$

There are some one say that $x = 1$ is also a real root. Therefore the given equation have there roots $x = -2$, $x = 2$, and $x = 1$.

I think that, When $x=1$, the expression $\sqrt{x^2-4}= \sqrt{-3}$. If we don't know about complex numbers, how to understand $\sqrt{-3}$?

I think, solve the given equation in Reals domain is different from find all real numbers satify the given equation.

Is my solution correct when I solve in Reals domain?

I used ***Mathematica*** to check.

[image]

[image]

And I asked my question at here https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/227446-How-Many-Solutions-Are-There-In-The-Equationx1

Even, ***Maple*** has a bug!

Comment: I don't see the need to work with inequalities. This equation is equivalent to $(x-1)\sqrt{x-2}\sqrt{x+2}=0$, so the solutions are when $x-1=0$, $\sqrt{x-2}=0$, or $\sqrt{x+2}=0$.

Comment: Your answer is correct as you have found all real numbers satisfying the equation.

Comment: @Dave Are you sure your solution is correct? If we consider in Real number, then $\sqrt{x^2-4} \neq \sqrt{x-2} \sqrt{x+2}.$.

Comment: Whether you know it or not, $ab = 0 \implies a = 0\ or\ b=0$ is valid in the complex numbers as well as the real numbers (that's because both the real numbers and the complex numbers satisfy the [field axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))). So if the first factor is 0, then the product is 0, whether the second factor is real or complex. Moreover, the first factor is 0 when $x = 1$, so that is a perfectly good *real* solution to the equation.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is solved by using the Zero Factor Property from algebra; i.e., $ab = 0$ iff $a = 0$ or $b=0$.

Hence, we have $x - 1 = 0$ or $x^{2} - 4 =  (x+2)(x-2) = 0$; giving

$$ x = 1; x = \pm 2 $$

Remark1: $x=1$ causes the second term to be imaginary; yet, as a commentator points out, is a real solution.

Therefore, the solution set is $$ x = 1; \pm 2.$$

Remark2: $\sqrt{x^{2}-4} = 0$ iff $x^{2}-4 = 0.$

Comment: If I have not known about complex number, I think, the solution `x = 1` is not a solution.

Comment: When `x=1`, the expression `\sqrt{x^2-4}= \sqrt{-3}`. If you don't know about complex numbers, how to understand ` \sqrt{-3}`?

Comment: @minhthien Thank you.

Comment: I don't vote for you. Because you did not read my solution carefully.

Comment: Only Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc'comment is enough for me.

Comment: @I.Chekhov: what difference does it make if the second factor is complex? The product is still 0.

Comment: The title suggests only real solutions.

Comment: $x = 1$ *is* a real solution.

Comment: @NickD Yes; you are right. I have edited the answer and alluded to your comment. Thank you.

Comment: I think solve in Reals domain is different from find all real numbers satify the given equation. See the pictures above my question.